# Firebase Authentification log in in unity always returns a new user

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I try to login into a firebase user account in Unity using authentication, but my problem is that if I use wrong credits or correct login credits(same result), I get a new user(email not verified...) returned. Is there any way I can fix it and get the correct user or none user if the user doesn't exist. The code below is everything I use for the authentification. Just in case someone misunderstands new user, a new user isn't created just the information I get is like the information a new account has.

I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

```
            using Firebase;
            using Firebase.Database;
            using Firebase.Unity.Editor;
            using Firebase.Auth;
            .
            .
            .
            FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance;
            app.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("this is my database url");
            if (app.Options.DatabaseUrl != null) 
                app.SetEditorDatabaseUrl(app.Options.DatabaseUrl);
            Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.GetAuth(app);
            auth.SignOut();//I don't know if this line is required, I just have it since I thought maybe the user is cached
            auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync("example@gmail.com", "any password").ContinueWith(task => {
                if (task.IsCanceled)
                {
                    Debug.LogError("Task was canceled.");
                    return;
                }
                if (task.IsFaulted)
                {
                    Debug.LogError("Task encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
                    return;
                }
                if (task.IsCompleted)
                {
                    //This case is true
                    Debug.Log("Task Completed");
                }
                Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
                Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})",
                    newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);
                Debug.Log(FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.GetEditorAuthUserId());//This is always the email adress
                Debug.Log(auth.CurrentUser.IsEmailVerified);//This is always false even if I use the correct password and email adress and verified it
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your google-services.json file is in your project. This is the issue that I had and after downloading the json file from my firebase console, the issue is resolved.